# How to delete .htaccess file with permission 0444

Tags: wordpress, malware

How we can do the same in FTP as server is not VPS. I have lots of .htaccess infected file in the server with permission(0444), i have to delete those file one by one and there are thousands of files. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the command line if you have ssh access and you're good at using the command line.

You can know the commands here
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-how-to-find-and-remove-files/

**NOTE: If you're not good with command lines then don't run anything directly on the server, practice in localhost then use in live server**

**Also, Make a full backup before doing anything**

You can follow these steps if you don't have SSH access.

1. download the fresh zip of wordpress and extract it then delete the wp-content dir from that extracted zip.
2. renamed wp-admin and wp-includes to wp-admin-new & wp-includes-new
3. then upload both folders to your server and rest replace the files wp-load.php, index.php, etc to your server.
4. then rename wp-admin and wp-includes(old ones) to wp-admin-bk & wp-includes-bk
5. then renamed wp-admin-new & wp-includes-new to wp-admin and wp-includes
6. Delete wp-admin-bk & wp-includes-bk folders.

Now your core files are clean, now follow these.

1. connect your FTP server using any FTP client. I am assuming you're using FileZilla
2. Goto wp-content folder then select, themes folder right click choose file permissions
3. set 664, check recursive into subdirectories, then choose to apply to files only.
4. repeat the same for the uploads and plugins folder.

Now you can scan again with WordFence and should be able to delete those files.

Comment: Hi @vijay Thank you for reply. I do not have SSH as its not VPS.

Comment: In that case, you can install WordFence or any other security plugin of your choice and then run the security scan. It will detect those files and will give you the option to delete them.

Comment: yes i have installed but it will not clean that file as it is 0444. not able to delete or repair that once

Comment: I've updated the answer and added new steps to do it manually.

Comment: Thank you but again the issue is i can not delete those folder as the permission is set to 0444 to all .htaccess files. When ever i am doing the same it shown me error folder is not empty and .htaccess files with 0444 permission is in more than thousand in number

Comment: Read my instructions clearly. I have explained how you can change the permission and delete them.

Comment: Sorry but can not modify lots of .htaccess file. i have set all unwanted folder to 0000 permission, but that is not good solution.